# How do I connect my Rails search form with the bootstrap search design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my search_form I created with Ruby -

```
        <%= form_tag(posts_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Posts" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
```

I don't like how it's so plain. I want it to look like the design that Bootstrap provide in its templates.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

So how do I use the bootstrap search form design, but still let it have proper search capabilities through my database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <%= form_tag(posts_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Posts", class: 'form-control' %>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag) and [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [twitter bootstrap gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails), and then this would be enough:

```
<%= form_tag(posts_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Posts" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```